# Mongos distribute too much query to one MongoD

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-query

We have a mongodb with 2 shardings, each of the shardings has those servers:

1. Shard 1: Master, running MongoD and Config server
2. Shard 1-s1: Slave, running MongoD and MongoS server
3. Shard 1-s2: Slave, running MongoD and MongoS and Arbiter server
4. Shard 2: Master, running MongoD and Config Server
5. Shard 2-s1: Slave, running MongoD and Config and MongoS server
6. Shard 2-s2: Slave, running MongoD and MongoS and Arbiter server

But the mongodb allways failed in recent days, after days of search, i find out that the MongoD runs at Shard 1(Master) always going down after reviced too many connections, other MongoD don't have this problem.

When the S1Master's MongoD running with too many connections for about 2 hours, the 4 Mongos Server will shut down one by one. Here is the Mongos's error log(10.81.4.72:7100 runs MongoD):

> Tue Aug 20 20:01:52 [conn8526] DBClientCursor::init call() failed
>   Tue Aug 20 20:01:52 [conn3897] ns: user.dev could not initialize cursor across all shards because : stale config detected for ns: user.
>   dev ParallelCursor::_init @ s01/10.36.31.36:7100,10.42.50.24:7100,10.81.4.72:7100 attempt: 0
>   Tue Aug 20 20:01:52 [conn744] ns: user.dev could not initialize cursor across all shards because : stale config detected for ns: user.d
>   ev ParallelCursor::_init @ s01/10.36.31.36:7100,10.42.50.24:7100,10.81.4.72:7100 attempt: 0

I don't know why this mongod revieved so many connections, the chunks shows the sharding works well.
[image]

Comment: and i thinks auto-sharding is not stable now, you can also give me some better advice to rebuilt the server.

Comment: which driver are you using?

Comment: Your config servers are out of sync and stale, what MongoDB version is this? Also what does your config server setup look like? Are they available at these times?

Comment: config servers are not available so that the mongos servers cann't run queries. MongoDB 2.0.7

Comment: Ah, OK well if that is a network problem then you need to ensure that it doesn't happen, at the end of the day if all 3 config servers (or however many you got) go down there is no way to ensure consistentcy, was this a network problem or are the config server pingable?